# Power Query - get values from other column and remove responding values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am looking for a way retrieve the following in power query:

[image]

Look into column A for values = 0 get the responding number C and
remove all responding numbers from the column C

It would be great if someone could give an advise how to achive this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by

- creating a new query and and in this created an "exclude" list, by copying the content from advanced editor to the exclude list
- filtering the Null values
- merging as new query "left anti join"
- and all the Null values and responding numbers are gone.

@Horseyride Thanks again for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Filter column A equal to zero using the drop down arrow atop column A

Merge the results back onto the original data set (requires a second table, or in example below, manual adjustment to code using home ... advance editor... )

Expand merged column C; will show data next to any row where A=0 for same C

Add custom column to remove any data in C where original C = merged C

```
=  if [C]=[C.1] then null else [C]
```

Remove extra columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([A] = 0)),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"C"},#"Filtered Rows",{"C"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"C"}, {"C.1"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", "New.C", each if [C]=[C.1] then null else [C]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"C", "C.1"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks Horseyride for this answer, I am still struggling with the implementation.

Comment: #"Gefilterte Zeilen3" = Table.SelectRows(#"Geänderter Typ1", each ([Zielmenge] = 0)),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Gefilterte Zeilen3",{"Ext.Lieferungsident."},#"Gefilterte Zeilen3",{"Ext.Lieferungsident."},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Erweiterte Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Ext.Lieferungsident."}, {"Table2.Ext.Lieferungsident."}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Erweiterte Table2", "New.Ext.Lieferungsident.", each if [#"Ext.Lieferungsident."]=[#"Table2.Ext.Lieferungsident."] then null else [#"Ext.Lieferungsident."])

Comment: in  #"Added Custom"

This is what I have now. That gives me 2 additional columns "Table2.Ext.Lieferungsident." with same numbers as in "Ext.Lieferungsident." in the request column "C" and "New.Ext.Lieferungsident." which should be "C.1" with "null" entries.